# Почему не работает простое регулярное выражение на Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Что не так, почему не работает, не находит?

```
QString str = "[]";
QRegularExpression reg1("\[\]");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = reg1.match(str);
if (match.hasMatch()) {
    qDebug() << "true";
}
```

Comment: удвой бекслеши...

Comment: спс большое, заработало

Comment: Или используйте raw string literals https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal